# Can we do something about the [mvc4] tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

We're having trouble getting the [mvc4](/questions/tagged/mvc4) tag to be automatically removed because people keep using it so much, since it shows up first in the tag suggestions list when you type in "mvc4".

Would it be possible to remove the [mvc4](/questions/tagged/mvc4) tag or make it a synonym of [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4) (though, the latter would only expand confusion between framework and design pattern for ASP.NET users) on Stack Overflow?

---

.. and another user (somewhat chronic help-vamp) made a topic in this tag:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327949/performance-with-inserting-in-to-multiple-tables-from-mvc4-c-sharp-application

Comment: You mean MVC4 is a design pattern as well as a framework? Never knew. Did ASP.NET MVC 4 reimagine the MVC pattern or something?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn , this is exactly, what i meant by "confusion". No, it is not a pattern. It is a simple misnaming. Just like if people would start to tag IE10 questions as [tag:internet-10]. Also, form ~10 post, that have been in this tag, most of them have no other ASP.NET MVC related tags, which means, that they would not be visible to the people, who actually understand the framework.

Comment: I've been nuking it every time it's been created.  Unfortunately it happens every few days, then sticks around for 12-48 hours based on how often others accidentally pick it rather than *think* about their tags.